# Possible Interface use as variable? C#

Tags: c#, interface

I have a piece of code, it concerns Interface and the Interface can use as variables. I don't understand this part. Does anyone know why?

```
 NameSpace MathTools
{
  Public delegate float FloatfromIntFloatFloatFloatBool(int i1,float f1,float f2,float f3, bool b1)

  Public Interface Ivaluable
  {
     float this [Icomparable key]{get;set;}
     int Count {get;}

     //Dico/Scalar results operators
     Ivaluable Plus(Ivaluable rightop); //Here is my question,Interface can use as variables?
  }
}
```

I guess the Interface(Ivaluable) works as a set of data type such as Int,Float

Then I tested my idea and I can declare a variable type as Ivaluable

```
IDictionary<String,Ivaluable> Sub=New Dictionary<String, Ivaluable>;//Ok
Ivaluable[] Sub1=new Ivaluable[]; //Ok
Sub.Add("whatever",Sub1); //Problem
```

But there is an error for the last line

> Argument Type MathTools.Ivaluable[] is not assignable to parameters
>   type MathTool.Ivaluable.

My last question is if Ivaluable is a set of data type where is the problem for the last line.

Comment: Did you try reading about the `Interface` keyword?

Comment: Please do some introductory reading on interfaces, and try using them in your code. `Ivaluable[] Sub1=new Ivaluable[];` should be `Ivaluable Sub1=new SomeClassImplementingIvaluable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an object of an interface.

You should create an object that implemnts your interface. 
And then do this(Lets assume that your class is **valueableObject** and this class implemnts your interface):

```
IDictionary<String,Ivaluable[]> Sub=New Dictionary<String, Ivaluable[]>;
Ivaluable[] Sub1=new valueableObject[2]; // 2 is just an example
Sub.Add("whatever",Sub1);
```

Comment: No, that's not correct. `Sub1` is still `Ivaluable[]` and you'll get the same error

Comment: @Kram you're right.Sub1  needs to be a class. But how can I solve the problem mentioned by Admit

Comment: Sub is a dictionary, I want for example Sub.Add("Date",DateArrays) is that possible?

Comment: if your dateArrays object implements from Ivalueable, you will be able to add it

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can be seen as a contract. When you create a class you have the option to say it implements a certain interface. When you do so you are basically telling that your class will implement all the properties and methods that are listed in the interface.

In your case there is probably a class somewhere that will implement the interface. There are a lot of good articles on the net which will explain this in detail. A nice start would be this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18743/Interfaces-in-C-For-Beginners